# Why receiving a SYNTAX error while ALTERing a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I have an existing SQL table and I am trying to add two more columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE DSPCONTENT01.dbo.RADRESULTSTOTALS2
ADD ([TEST1] INT,
       [TEST2] INT);
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use parentheses.

```
ALTER TABLE DSPCONTENT01.dbo.RADRESULTSTOTALS2
ADD
    [TEST1] INT,
    [TEST2] INT
```

Comment: Have to wait 5 mins :/